# ArcGIS Experience Builder: Application does not show organizations basemap gallery

Tags: basemap, arcgis-portal, arcgis-enterprise, arcgis-experience-builder

I am working with ArcGIS Experience Builder Developer Edition to build an application.

How I understand the docs and how it is described at [Configure Basemaps in Experience Builder?](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-experience-builder/configure-basemaps-in-experience-builder/td-p/592237), the basemap gallery shown in the application should be the one from the organisation (ArcGIS Enterprise).

However, this does not seem to work for me. Even though I have a basemap gallery defined in my Portal for ArcGIS (which works in the Portal), my application shows a different list (ESRI basemaps).
This is the list I get:

[image]

Do I lack some configuration somewhere or is something else wrong?

The connection between the application and my Portal seems to be fine, as I draw all my data and a Geocoding service from it successfully.

Comment: Can you confirm, if you open your Portal's map viewer and change the basemap, do you get the list you see above, or do you get your custom list?

Comment: I confirm that in the Portal's Map Viewer I do not get the list above, but my custom list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this is a known bug for the current build of Experience Builder. It will be resolved in the next release.

- More information can be found at [Map Widget Not Showing Organization Basemaps](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-experience-builder/map-widget-not-showing-organization-basemaps/m-p/1019810)
- A possible workaround with a custom basemap widget can be found at [Experience Builder Developer Edition - Issues with Basemap gallery](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-experience-builder/experience-builder-developer-edition-issues-with-basemap-gallery/m-p/1044892#M1712)